# JavaScript - Loop through Object to find Specific Key Value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, loops

I have a file called `contentful.json` which is stored in the root of my directory.

This is what that file looks like:

`[{
    "URL": "/force",
    "SpaceID": "2g1335I9GYQCKwmQYCuSSI"
}, {
    "URL": "/heroku",
    "SpaceID": "2g1335I9GYQCKwmQYCuSSI"
}, {
    "URL": "/slack",
    "SpaceID": "2g1335I9GYQCKwmQYCuSSI"
}, {
    "URL": "/contentful",
    "SpaceID": "2g1335I9GYQCKwmQYCuSSI"
}, {
    "URL": "/openShift",
    "SpaceID": "2g1335I9GYQCKwmQYCuSSI"
}]`

I then have a file called `contentful.js`.

Which looks like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

let obj;

fs.readFile('./contentful.json', 'utf8', (err, jsonData) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  obj = JSON.parse(jsonData);

  // Method One
  for (let i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++) {
    console.log(obj.URL);
    // ...
  }

  // Method Two
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    if (key.url === '/heroku') {
      console.log(key.SpaceID);
    }
  });
});
```

What I am trying to do is read the `contentful.json` file from the `contentful.js` file. Which works.

Then I am trying to loop through that file and find a specific value.

E.G loop through the JSON object, and where URL equals a dynamic value (/force) return me the SpaceID.

So this JSON object could be **n** big. I have attempted two solutions but don't think I am quite their yet.

I need to input a URL into the `contnetful.js` file and if that URL matches the URL in the `contnetful.json` file I would like it to return that SpaceID.

Comment: the output of `console.log(obj.URL)` is `undefined`. It prints `undefined` out as many time as the size of the JSON object. In this case 5. However for Method Two `console.log(key.SpaceID);` it doesn't print anything out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change method one from this:

```
  // Method One
  for (let i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++) {
    console.log(obj.URL);
    // ...
  }
```

to this:

```
  // Method One
  for (let i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++) {
    console.log(obj[i].URL);
    if (obj[i].URL === someVariable) {
        console.log("found match for ", someVariable);
        console.log("SpaceID = ", obj[i].SpaceID);
    }
    // ...
  }
```

You have to use the index in your `for` loop to index into the `obj` array to get the object at that spot in the array.

If you want the URL you are looking for to be in a variable, then just use a variable in your comparison.  You can wrap the whole thing in a function and pass the desired string into the function as an argument to the function and then you can reuse the function to match different values.

Comment: still no dynamic URL.

Comment: @DominikNoll - Change `"/force"` to a variable if you want.

Comment: Thats the answer to his question :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use filter to check for the dynamic URL. It will return the filtered matches of a particular URL. You can get the spaceID then from the filtered result.

```js
let obj;

let dynamicURL = "/heroku"

obj = [{
  "URL": "/force",
  "SpaceID": "2g1335I9GYQCKwmQYCuSSI"
}, {
  "URL": "/heroku",
  "SpaceID": "2g1335I9GYQCKwmQYCuSSI"
}, {
  "URL": "/slack",
  "SpaceID": "2g1335I9GYQCKwmQYCuSSI"
}, {
  "URL": "/contentful",
  "SpaceID": "2g1335I9GYQCKwmQYCuSSI"
}, {
  "URL": "/openShift",
  "SpaceID": "2g1335I9GYQCKwmQYCuSSI"
}]

var filtered = obj.filter(function(elem){
 return (elem.URL == dynamicURL)
});

console.log(filtered[0].SpaceID);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Method One:
function searchForUrl(obj, url){
    for(let i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++){
        if(obj[i].Url == url){
            //DO STUFF
            break; //better performance, only if the URL is unique!!
        }
    }
}

//Method Two:
function searchForUrl(obj, url){
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    if (key.url === url) {
      console.log(key.SpaceID);
    }
});
```